# How to loop the program back to the beginning with user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm setting up a basic hangman game and am trying to get the program to loop back to the beginning when the game is finished.

```
    print("Welcome to Hangman")
    print("Start guessing")

    word = "hangman"
    guesses = ''
    turns = 10

    while turns > 0:
        failed = 0
        for char in word:
            if char in guesses:
                print (char),
            else:
                print("_"),
                failed += 1
        if failed == 0:
            print("You won")
            print("Play Again? (y/n)")
            break
        guess = input("Guess a character:")
        guesses += guess
        if guess not in word:
            turns -= 1
            print("wrong")
            print("You have", + turns, "more guesses")
            if turns == 0:
                print("You Lose")
                print("Play again? (y/n)")
```

Comment: A quick way would be to throw this into a function and call that function on Losing by seeing the users raw_input(), if yes, call the function else exit.

Comment: @KyleJ That sounds dangerously like an endless recursion which isn't endless because it will eventually end in an `RecursionError`. Recursion isn't a suitable substitute for loops in languages without guaranteed tail call optimization.

Comment: @BlackJack Definitely if the user decides to play an absurd amount of games. But I would always press for a loop.

Comment: @KyleJ The thing is: this is a beginner question and this site and answers are read by beginners, so if they see such a recursion they just copy it and may start using it for other loops as well. It's a habit that shouldn't even start to sink in. IMHO. ☺

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your game in a function and throw it in a while loop.
After the play game function, they'll be asked to play again. If they respond with anything but 'y', the loop breaks.

```
while True:
    # play_game()
    if input("Play again?") != 'y':
        break
print("Thanks for playing!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an user input and a while loop

```
play_again = "Y"
while play_again == "Y" or play_again == "y":
    print("Welcome to Hangman")
    print("Start guessing")

    word = "hangman"
    guesses = ''
    turns = 10

    while turns > 0:
        failed = 0
        for char in word:
            if char in guesses:
                print (char),
            else:
                print("_"),
                failed += 1
        if failed == 0:
            print("You won")
            print("Play Again? (y/n)")
            break
        guess = input("Guess a character:")
        guesses += guess
        if guess not in word:
            turns -= 1
            print("wrong")
            print("You have", + turns, "more guesses")
            if turns == 0:
                print("You Lose")
                play_again = input("Play again? (Y/N)")
```

or in short just put in in a function:

```
play_again = "Y"
while play_again == "Y" or play_again == "y":
    game()
    play_again = input("Play again? (Y/N)")
```

Comment: You are mixing `input()` and `raw_input()` here.  `input()` shouldn't be used in Python 2.x because it allows the user to input arbitrary Python expressions that get evaluated.  Python 2 shouldn't be used any more anyway: https://pythonclock.org/

Comment: You are absolutely correct, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

You could put it all into a function and have it loop back like this:

```py
def start():
    replay = True
    while (replay):
        game_started()
        inp = input("Play again? Y/n ")
        if inp == 'n' or inp == 'N':
            replay = False

def game_started():
    print("Welcome to Hangman")
    print("Start guessing")

    word = "hangman"
    guesses = ''
    turns = 10

    while turns > 0:
        failed = 0
        for char in word:
            if char in guesses:
                print (char),
            else:
                print("_"),
                failed += 1
        if failed == 0:
            print("You won")
            break
        guess = input("Guess a character:")
        guesses += guess
        if guess not in word:
            turns -= 1
            print("wrong")
            print("You have", + turns, "more guesses")
            if turns == 0:
                print("You Lose")
                break

start()
```

Edit:
Your check if a letter was guesses is also flawed:
If you guess "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", you always win.
I'd suggest checking the length of the input before appending it to `guesses`.
Also, to print it all into one line, you could use "print(char, end='')" (and "print('_', end='')", respectively). Just make sure to print a newline after the loop, to finish the line.

Answer (score -1):

Hey friend here is what I came up with I hope it helps! Instead of using your turns to control the while loop you can use a "running" variable that is set to a boolean which you can use input statements for your replay feature to control when you want to exit (False) or continue through your loop (True).

```
print("Welcome to Hangman")
print("Start guessing")

word = "hangman"
guesses = ''
turns = 10
running = True

while running:

    failed = 0
    for char in word:
        if char in guesses:
            print(char),
        else:
            print("_"),
            failed += 1

    if failed <= 0:
        print("You won")
        x = input("Play Again? (y/n) \n")
        if x == "y":
            turns = 10
        else:
            running = False

    guess = input("Guess a character: \n")
    guesses += guess

    if guess not in word:
        turns -= 1
        print("wrong")
        print("You have", + turns, "more guesses")

        if turns == 0:
            print("You Lose")
            z = input("Play Again? (y/n) \n")
            if z == "y":
                turns = 10
            else:
                running = False
```